# How to check if a document il linked to another in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose that I have two collections:

*Users*

```
_id:5c810da8c714a02e84d16d16
username:foo
```

*Tokens*

```
_id: 5c81347b00370c2848db8725
_userId: 5c810da8c714a02e84d16d16
token: "83790bf08fa16eec1c3c6761d0c1be4f"
```

I'm trying to check if the token with id `5c81347b00370c2848db8725` is linked to the user with id `5c810da8c714a02e84d16d16`.

The first problem is that I only have the username to find the user details, so this is my solution:

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, async function (err, user) {
    let token = await Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token });

    console.log(token._userId);
    console.log(user._id);
    console.log(token._userId != user._id);

    if (token == null || token._userId != user._id) {
       //Error happened..
    }
});
```

now the code above will return the following result:

```
5c810da8c714a02e84d16d16
5c810da8c714a02e84d16d16
true
```

but should return `false` because the record are equal.. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality operator is mostly useful for comparing native types, such as strings. In MongoDB, the `ObjectID` is an object that cannot be compared with `==` operator.

Mongoose uses the mongodb-native driver. These use the native `ObjectID` type from the Mongodb driver. Object IDs can be compared using the `.equals()` method.

With your example, you should write your check as:

```
user._id.equals(token._userId)
```

[Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals)

Note that if you want to use Equal, you should convert the ObjectIDs to strings prior to making the comparison:

```
user._id.toString() === token._userId.toString()
```

Comment: ok so essentially mine solution didn't works because the object are not string but object of mongo

Comment: That is correct